How to Ensure an App Displays Over the Lock Screen in Both Foreground and Background States?
I'm developing an app that replaces the lock screen, similar to what apps like CashSlide do. My primary goal is to enable this "lock screen replacement" feature, putting aside other functionalities for now.
The main challenge I'm facing might be due to my transition from web development to experimenting with Android, so I may be missing something fundamental.
I uploaded my code on github: https://github.com/helloheesu/temp_android/
Here are the detail situation:

I've set setShowWhenLocked(true), and the app appears over the lock screen when it's in the foreground.
However, when the app goes to the background (e.g., when returning to the home screen), it no longer appears over the lock screen.
I tried using a foreground service to maintain operation in the background, verifying it by adding a MediaPlayer, which continues to play music even when the app is in the background. In other words, media play continues, but app doesn't render.
I thought using a dynamic BroadcastReceiver to handle the screen-off intent and then triggering the main activity might work, but this approach hasn't been successful.

Since there are no explicit errors and the app simply doesn't behave as expected, I'm struggling to even find a starting point for debugging as a beginner in Android development. Any advice on where the issue might lie or how to investigate this would be greatly appreciated.
